# Presenting interstitial ads with SpriteKit restarts entire scene

Tags: ios, admob, sprite-kit

I am trying to display an admob interstitial ad after receiving a successful ad call  :

```
- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)ad {
    DLog(@"interstitialDidReceiveAd");
    [ad presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
```

`self` is the `ViewController` instance (which is the root view controller as implemented by the SpriteKit template) and for some reason it displays the ad (which is good) but restarts the entire scene.

I should note that the ad request is done way after the scene is created and being run.

I also noticed this behavior when I tried adding a view to this controller's view property (which is a SpriteKit `SKView` instance)

And ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I thought... I was doing something wrong...

If you stumble upon this problem :

I create my scene in the view controller's method `viewWillLayoutSubviews` (until this method the view bounds are NOT updated with the desired orientation)

When the interstitial ad is presented this method is called again and of course the scene is recreated as well. So just add a boolean member indicating if the scene was already loaded for creating the scene only once.

Poof, problem is gone:)

Comment: will you please help me. how you make that problem solved ,i didn't get your answer

Comment: viewWillLayoutSubviews is called when the interstitial ad is dismissed. Since I created my scene in this method it was recreated again.

Answer (score 0):

There's something funky going on here that's more than just displaying an interstitial. I have a sprite kit project setup where I display the UIImagePickerController from the rootViewController via:

```
#pragma mark - ImageCatureDelegate methods

-(void)requestImagePicker
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [UIImagePickerController new];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        SKTexture *imageTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:image];

        CIFilter *sepia = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone"];
        [sepia setValue:@(0.8) forKey:kCIInputIntensityKey];
        imageTexture = [imageTexture textureByApplyingCIFilter:sepia];

        SKView *view = (SKView *)self.view;
        MyScene *currentScene = (MyScene *)view.scene;
        [currentScene setPhotoTexture:imageTexture];
    }];
}
```

during the callback, nothing special is done except dismissing the modal. If admob is pushing a new VC you may see this issue, but if it's displaying a literal modal VC modally... then you shouldn't see this issue. You may want to look into exactly what happens when you push an interstitial ad. If this is the case, and this is the only method you can use, You'll have to NSCode or something to keep the game's state so it can be loaded back up when the interstitial disappears.

Edit:

To append to your solution above, if you use viewWillLayoutSubviews to correct the portrait/landscape issue in SpriteKit, be sure to do it as such so this only happens 'once'

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;

    if (!skView.scene) {
        skView.showsFPS = YES;
        skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

        // Create and configure the scene.
        MyScene * scene = [[MyScene alloc] initWithSize:skView.bounds.size andLevelNumber:1];
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

        // Present the scene.
        [skView presentScene:scene];
    }
}
```

Comment: Restoring the entire game state will be impractical in my case and this issue seems to be either a bug or something I'm doing wrong. I don't see a reason why pushing another VC should cause the entire scene to be loaded from scratch. If it works for you then I am probably doing something wrong

Comment: Yea sorry. I have a feeling that you may want to verify what's truly going on (if the interstitial is truly a modal... which there are methods you can call against the displayed object to try to find out) and how your states change during the Scene's loading. The big thing you'll want to test is if your Scene is being initialized from scratch (which is your biggest hint as to what's going on). Since there isn't a state held on your Scene, it must be re initializing itself (just verify this in the initializer methods).

Comment: Thanks for the help but I figured out how to solve this. I posted an answer with the solution.